# How to sort a vector of indices based on the indexed values in another vector?

Tags: sorting, vector, rust

I have a struct of the shape

```
pub struct ExampleData {
    data: Vec<u32>,
    data_ids: Vec<u32>,
}
```

Sample data

```
{data: [9,8,7], data_ids: [0,1,2]}
```

I want to sort the `data_ids` vector based on the values of the `data` vector and I have implemented the following method:

```
impl ExampleData {
    pub fn sorting(&mut self) {
        self.data_ids.sort_by(|a, b| self.data[a].cmp(self.data[b]));
    }
}
```

The above code does not work:

```
error[E0277]: the type `[u32]` cannot be indexed by `&u32`
  --> src/lib.rs:10:38
   |
10 |         self.data_ids.sort_by(|a, b| self.data[a].cmp(self.data[b]));
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
   |
   = help: the trait `SliceIndex<[u32]>` is not implemented for `&u32`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Index<&u32>` for `Vec<u32>`
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [The duplicates applied to your question](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e2cd3edf39f1fb1319b70e572e75add9), but I'd encourage [using `sort_by_key` instead](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=862fb35ee7d2d64be3a1de7c9ac4f54f).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, works like a charm.